# several javascript calls made into one

Tags: javascript

Hi I am very new to javascript and I have made a lot of buttons on a site which have different calls. They are all the same minus the results which are pretty much like hide.1 and show.2 etc. Its pretty big but there must be a way to make it smaller? Its no biggy just bad coding that i would like not to get in the habbit of doing. And the only reason for (a) after some of them is that the call doesnt works twice, so when i set it show in a full size screen and a mobile screen it does not work right? Thanks

The code is :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-continue').on('click', function() {
      $('#loginbox').hide(); 
      $('#1box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next1').on('click', function() {
      $('#1box').hide(); 
      $('#2box').show();
   })
});



$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next2').on('click', function() {
      $('#2box').hide(); 
      $('#3box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back2').on('click', function() {
      $('#2box').hide(); 
      $('#1box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next2a').on('click', function() {
      $('#2box').hide(); 
      $('#3box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back2a').on('click', function() {
      $('#2box').hide(); 
      $('#1box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next3').on('click', function() {
      $('#3box').hide(); 
      $('#4box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back3').on('click', function() {
      $('#3box').hide(); 
      $('#2box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next3a').on('click', function() {
      $('#3box').hide(); 
      $('#4box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back3a').on('click', function() {
      $('#3box').hide(); 
      $('#2box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next4').on('click', function() {
      $('#4box').hide(); 
      $('#5box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back4').on('click', function() {
      $('#4box').hide(); 
      $('#3box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-next4a').on('click', function() {
      $('#4box').hide(); 
      $('#5box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back4a').on('click', function() {
      $('#4box').hide(); 
      $('#3box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back5').on('click', function() {
      $('#5box').hide(); 
      $('#4box').show();
   })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-back5a').on('click', function() {
      $('#5box').hide(); 
      $('#4box').show();
   })
});
```

And the calls work like this :

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 controls hidden-xs">
    <div><button id='btn-back2' name ='back2' type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Back</button></div></div><div class="hidden-xs"><button id='btn-next2' name ='next2' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Next</button></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 controls hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div><button id='btn-back2a' name ='back2a' type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Back</button></div></div><div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><button id='btn-next2a' name ='next2a' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Next</button></div
```

>

Comment: simply remove `});

$(document).ready(function() {` between each "block"

Comment: @JaromandaX: that only removes part of the duplication, though.

Comment: yes, but it's a 40% reduction in code already :p

Comment: True.  I just think it can be reduced much further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would make sense:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const buttons = [
    ['btn-continue', 'loginbox', '1box'],
    ['btn-next1', '1box', '2box'],
    ['btn-next2', '2box', '3box'],
    ['btn-back2', '2box', '1box'],
    ['btn-next2a', '2box', '3box'],
    ['btn-back2a', '2box', '1box'],
    ['btn-next3', '3box', '4box'],
    ['btn-back3', '3box', '2box'],
    ['btn-next3a', '3box', '4box'],
    ['btn-back3a', '3box', '2box'],
    ['btn-next4', '4box', '5box'],
    ['btn-back4', '4box', '3box'],
    ['btn-next4a', '4box', '5box'],
    ['btn-back4a', '4box', '3box'],
    ['btn-back5', '5box', '4box'],
    ['btn-back5a', '5box', '4box']
  ]
  buttons.forEach(function(b) {
    $('#' + b[0]).on('click', function() {
      $('#' + b[1]).hide(); 
      $('#' + b[2]).show();
    });
  });
});
```

This captures the repetitive data in a single structure, and replaces the repetitive code with a loop.

**Note** that this is entirely untested.

Comment: Thats works a treat, thankyour very much and gives me a good and totally different way of looking at how to do it!

Comment: I'm glad it works, but look too at the solution from bryjohns, which is much more maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

Just make it more generic. You can use classes or data attributes. There is a lot of different ways to do this.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vouvcedj/4/

There is still a lot of cleanup that can be done but this should be pretty clear as to what you can do.

JS

```
$(function() {
    var handleFirstLast = function() {
        if ($('.shown').is('.section:first')) {
            $('#btn-back').hide();
        } else {
            $('#btn-back').show();
        }

        if ($('.shown').is('.section:last')) {
          $('#btn-forward').hide();
        } else {
            $('#btn-forward').show();
        }
    }

    handleFirstLast();
    $('#btn-back').on('click', function(e) {
        // find the currently shown section and get the previous
        // https://api.jquery.com/next/
        var $showing = $('.section.shown');
        $showing.prev().removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        $showing.removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
        handleFirstLast();

    });
    $('#btn-forward').on('click', function(e) {
        var $showing = $('.section.shown');
        $showing.next().removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        $showing.removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
        handleFirstLast();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="sections">
    <div class="section shown">
        section 1
    </div>
    <div class="section hidden">
        section 2
    </div>
    <div class="section hidden">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
     <button id="btn-back">Back</button>
     <button id="btn-forward">Forward</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which do you think is the best way? second way seems more workable. Loads of free ones out there but you have to change so much you might as well do your own i think? And wth the second one, how can you define where is the start and finish, ie no back at the begging and finish at the end?

Comment: Yes, to make this work properly, you will also have to account for first and last sections, but that shouldn't be too hard to do, and it would definitely make maintenance easier.

Comment: It's up to you, usually something more generic is preferable. It looks like you're using bootstrap. Take a look at their source for JS to get some more ideas. They keep their stuff pretty straight forward. I'll add the fix for being on the first and last and a js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle and it is one of the core principles in programming. If you find yourself repeating in code, means trouble, a small change can be catastrophic for you if you need to go to each place and implement it.

With DRY principle you write code once and reuse it via numerous techniques. A change can be applied once and to one place only.

> When the DRY principle is applied successfully, a modification of any
>   single element of a system does not require a change in other
>   logically unrelated elements. Additionally, elements that are
>   logically related all change predictably and uniformly, and are thus
>   kept in sync.

You code can be changed to something like this:

```
var myNs = myNs || {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(myNs.map).each(function(index, value) {
    $(value.clickedElement).on('click', clickHandler.bind(this, value));
  });

  function clickHandler(value) {
    $(value.hideElement).hide();
    $(value.showElement).show();
  }
});
```

What about the `myNs`? This is a configuration object, a namespace to load your configuration for elements. This can be a completely different JavaScript file, which of course is loaded before this particular script.

Example:

```
// This can be in a completely different file
var myNs = {
  map: [{
    clickedElement: '#btn-continue',
    hideElement: '#loginbox',
    showElement: '#1box'
  }, {
    clickedElement: '#btn-next1',
    hideElement: '#1box',
    showElement: '#2box'
  }, {
    clickedElement: '#btn-next2',
    hideElement: '#2box',
    showElement: '#3box'
  }, {
    clickedElement: '#btn-back2',
    hideElement: '#2box',
    showElement: '#1box'
  },
  ...
  ]
};
```

You can take this a step forward and use the new ES6 modules or even AMD modules. Of course you need a module loader for that, like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Check out the following [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZ9Qlv?p=preview) to peak on some code.